# Creating a list based on a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to create a dropdown list in sheet A based on the values in sheet B in column A. I clicked on the A column in B sheet and named it as `Models`. Then I clicked on the cell in sheet A where I wanted the list to be and selected `Data -> Data validation -> Data validation`. In the `Settings` page I selected `List` in the `Allow` section, checked `Ignore blank` and `In-cell dropdown`. In the `Source` section I inserted `=Models`.

This way I get all the right values plus a lot of blank values. How do I prevent the blank lines from appearing in the list?

Comment: format the range as an Excel Table,, the range will automatically expand when you add new rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dynamic Named Range` to specify the validation lint

Assuming the list data start at cell `B!A1` and extends down without gaps, put this in the List reference

```
=OFFSET(B!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(B!$A:$A),1)
```

This formula adapts to the number of entries in `B!A:A`, so if you add or delete data, the validation list automatically adapts